# Test if a bit is set in a BitSet on the left hand side of a rule

Tags: java, drools

I have a member which is a `BitSet`, and in a given rule, I'd like to test whether a particular bit is set, for example:

```
class Foo
{
  BitSet bar;
  // getter & setter
}
```

My rule that I would like:

```
rule "Test Bitset"
  when
    $f : Foo(bar ???) <-- what does this look like?
  then
    // do something
end
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `$f : Foo(bar get 3)`?

Comment: @Vlad, what is this `get`? and anyway - it doesn't compile. (I know `get()` is a member of `BitSet`, but there is no keyword `get` AFAIK in Drools)

Comment: sorry, am not familiar with Drools syntax, I just assumed it could work by analogy to `contains`. Hence commented, not answered.

Comment: Not familiar with Drool either, but from the docs Foo(bar.get(3)) seems valid.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö, ahhhh, the most obvious solution! :) I thought I tried that, but clearly not! Post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs

```
Foo(bar.get(3))
```

would be a valid way to do it.

[Drools doc](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Beta1/drools-expert-docs/html_single/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works:

```
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
bitSet.set(3);
bitSet.set(1);

int index = 3;
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setBar( bitSet );

BitSet bits = foo.getBar();
System.out.print( bits.get(index) );
```

That prints "true" as the BitSet for decimal 10 results in binary 1010, the 4th bit (reading from the right, zero indexed) is 1, so true.

You should be able to transpose that into your algorithm.

Comment: The point of the question is, what is the syntax for testing a bit in Drools, not how `BitSet` works in Java!